# What substance Tachikawa Yuko used on the Shimada Hideo's parasyte in the art club?

Tags: parasyte

Yuko takes a vial from the art kit to use as a weapon against Shimada, in case he turns aggressive.

> He does turn aggressive, murdering 17 students.

The anime shows the label (in Japanese) of the vial.

What substance was that?

Comment: Due to Crunchyroll DRM features, no SS of the label available.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Paint stripper]

The Japanese label is `油彩剥離剤`, which translates to [paint stripper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint_stripper).

> The principal active ingredient in historically common solvent paint strippers is [dichloromethane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichloromethane), also called methylene chloride, which has serious health risks including death.

> Symptoms of acute overexposure to dichloromethane via inhalation include: difficulty concentrating, dizziness, fatigue, nausea, headaches, numbness, weakness, and irritation of the upper respiratory tract and eyes.

> DCM is also metabolized by the body to carbon monoxide potentially leading to carbon monoxide poisoning.

> Prolonged skin contact can result in DCM dissolving some of the fatty tissues in skin, resulting in skin irritation or chemical burns.

Comment: That would certainly be consistent with the effects shown.